# How Do I Updated a Sequelize Model with An Association?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update a sequelize model (called conversation) whenever I insert a value into its association (called message). The conversation model doesn't automatically update, and I haven't found any useful information in the docs.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const { Conversation, Message } = require("../../db/models");
const onlineUsers = require("../../onlineUsers");

// expects {recipientId, text, conversationId } in body (conversationId will be null if no conversation exists yet)
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    const senderId = req.user.id;
    const { recipientId, text, conversationId, sender } = req.body;

    // if we already know conversation id, we can save time and just add it to message and return
    if (conversationId) {
      const message = await Message.create({ senderId, text, conversationId });
      Conversation.update({ })
      return res.json({ message, sender });
    }
    // if we don't have conversation id, find a conversation to make sure it doesn't already exist
    let conversation = await Conversation.findConversation(
      senderId,
      recipientId
    );

    if (!conversation) {
      // create conversation
      conversation = await Conversation.create({
        user1Id: senderId,
        user2Id: recipientId,
      });
      if (onlineUsers.includes(sender.id)) {
        sender.online = true;
      }
    }
    const message = await Message.create({
      senderId,
      text,
      conversationId: conversation.id,
    });
    res.json({ message, sender });
  } 
  catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: At least you forgot `await` with `Conversation.update({ })`

Answer (score 0):

for update you must change or append data into your record
and second argument is your condition for filter users (if you didnt pass argument for condition it means you didnt want to filter conversations then updade all of the records

```
   await conversation.update(
  { title: 'sample title' },
  { where: {  : 2 } }
    )
```

Comment: @moon-shine Was your question solved with my answer?